# На сайте виснут страницы

Tags: php, yii2

Сайт написан на Yii2. Рандомно любая страница может долго получать ответ. Все страницы работают, а на одну не возможно зайти сек 30-40. Причём если зайти на страницу в режиме инкогнито она сразу загружается. В чём может быть проблема? Пробовал скрипты отключать, даже если в контроллере die прописать всё равно тупит.

Comment: а где сам сайт размешен? Пробовали ли на вкладке networks в браузере посмотреть ситуацию? А с статическими страницами такое наблюдается?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала надо бы посмотреть профайлер, что там происходит с запросом, если в профайлере все окей, то возможно проблема с сервером. Хотя если дело в одном экшне только, то скорее всего профайлер выявит проблему, подозреваю что там какой-то медленный запрос к базе